# 64 Bit Raspberry OS MongoDB

Tags: 64-bit, mongodb

It appears that MongoDB only supports arm64 architecture via [Ubuntu](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/#supported-platforms). Does this mean the only way to run the current version of MongoDB is with the Ubuntu Raspberry PI image or is there another way to install it on the official 64 bit Raspberry PI OS that is currently in beta? Most resources online recommend using an older version of MongoDB.

Comment: I think 3.2 or above is only 64bit but you should be able to install the last released version for Buster (32-bit obviously) by `apt install`

Comment: I was hoping to install the current version of MongoDB. Currently I am trying to compile it on my RPI (which has the beta 64bit Raspberry Pi OS) but it looks like I need to update Python... while needs other packages updated... and down the rabbit hole I go.

Comment: The rabbit hole swallowed me and I was ultimately unable to compile it (something I have never done before). If anyone comes across a way to get this done, I would love to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

Binaries and detailed cross-compilation instructions can be found [here](https://github.com/themattman/mongodb-raspberrypi-binaries). I am running MongoDB 6.x on 64-bit Debian on a Pi 4.

MongoDB does not officially support the Pi platform because the ARM processors on Pi's do not support LSE (large system extensions). Therefore I have aimed to provide community-edition binaries on a best-effort basis.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).